# How to have order summary moved from the mini cart to the page in checkout (mobile)

Tags: cart, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.3, order-summary, mobile-menu

On my checkout on my theme, I have the order summary condensed into a mobile menu when it's mobile. The issue with this is that we are having issues in regards to make it more obvious what is in the cart when they get to the checkout page.

The solve I am looking for is kind of the cart to appear on the shipping/billing page as opposed to the mini cart in the upper right.

The way it is on the sidebar for the desktop is great. However, I would like a stacking version where it doesn't have the mini cart and just puts it right on the page like the desktop version (except not the sidebar, but would accept stacked above).

Removing the mini cart on the header is something I can do via the XML after this is dealt with.

I'm guessing there may be something with breakpoints that could be used here that will help?

Thank you!